# Laravel 5.0 ajax doesn't work

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have mistake with firebug : "500 (Internal Server Error)".

I begin with Ajax and I would like understand a simply thing:

```
$("#boutonRecherche").click(function () {
$.ajax({
url : "/recherche", //I have tried rechercheController.php and ...
                     //...Http/Controllers/Phases/RechercheController.php
type : "POST",
data : '&controle=1',//after comments I found this lines triggers error in
                     //...firebug
dataType : "html"
});
});
```

1. What is the best path for the url ?
2. How to fix "500 (Internal Server Error)"

View code:

```
{!! Form::open(['url'=>'recherche']) !!}
{!! Form::submit('solaire',['class'=>'btn btn-primary', 'name'=>'recherche', 
'id'=>'boutonRecherche']) !!}
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

My paths :

1. My Controller Http/Controllers/Phases/RechercheController.php
2. My View public/resources/views/phases/recherche.blade.php
3. My JS dans public/script.js

Thanks in advance ;)

Comment: Error 500 is usually caused by mistake in your code, please check, if you haven't made a typo. Next problem may be with type of request. Is POST request allowed for this route ?

Comment: Yes it is a post request, my route looks like 
    Route::post("/recherche","Phases\RechercheController@update"); I have checked my typo.

Answer (score 0):

POST request needs `CSRF token`.
When you are sending form, add to `data` object in AJAX field `{_token: csrfToken}`.

The `csrfToken` you can parse from form or from `<head>` where you create `<meta name="csrf_token" content="{{csrf_token()}}">` field.

If you want to send GET param, append it to url, so `url : "/recherche?controle=1"`